# Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I had a project with netcoreapp3.0 , using entity framework, everything was working untill it stopped, so I decided to re create the project by creating a new project, and manually creating the classes and copy/paste inside (changing namepsaces ofcourse).

the new project is netcoreapp3.1, I was trying to add a new table to the database by adding :

```
  public DbSet<UsersCredentialsModel> UsersCredentialsModels { get; set; }
```

to the AppDbContext class, but when running it wouldn't add it and gave errors.

I deleted the database by going to Sql Server object exp and clicking on delete.
I removed the migration folder.

when I try to Add-Migration "name"
I get

```
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: One or more errors occurred. (Failure occurred during job recovery.)
```

Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here are snippets from the project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Models;

namespace DatabaseContext
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Message>().Property(m => m.Service).HasConversion<int>();
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<Message>(m => m.Messages).WithOne(u => u.User).IsRequired();
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }


        public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UsersCredentialsModel> UsersCredentialsModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the ConfigureServices startup method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("AutoLoverDbConnection"),x => x.MigrationsAssembly("AutoMatcherProject")));
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddTransient<ISche, SchedulerImpl>();
        services.AddTransient<IQueue, QueueImpl>();
        services.AddTransient<SchedulerJob>();
        services.AddTransient<IBotFactory,BotFactory>();
        //services.AddTransient<ICredentialSaver, CredentialSaver.CredentialSaver>();
        services.AddSingleton(provider => _scheduler);
        services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(options => {
            options.AppId = "";
            options.AppSecret = "";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        });
        _scheduler.Clear();
    }
```

[image]

EDIT:

after running add-migration "name" -verbose this the stack trace I got:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'AppDbContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'AutoMatcherProject1.Models.AppDbContext'.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

whats funny is that it worked on the older project with the current constructor so I dont know what's the problem..
searched the internet but nothing really helps, I would appreciate anything!

Answer (score 0):

I did some steps and the migration worked, what I did is adding the migration assembly in the startup

```C#
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
x => x.MigrationsAssembly("MyMigrationAssemblyProjectName")));
}
```

Then I set up the project that has the startup.cs as a startup project, and added a migration, so it asked me to add the package

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

after installing the package, I run the migration, it asked me to choose the project of the migration assembly, I chose it, and it worked